# Why is Spark RDD partitioner ignoring some partition IDs returned by Partitioner::getPartition()?

Tags: apache-spark

Invalid partition IDs are being computed when calling `JavaPairRDD<String, Long>::repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(StringPartitioner)`, where `StringPartitioner` is my own `Partitioner` subclass.  It is as if the Spark RDD source code is somehow modifying the partition numbers my `StringPartitioner` is returning.  My `StringPartitioner` class is:

```java
public class StringPartitioner extends Partitioner {
    private int partitions;

    public StringPartitioner(int partitions) {
        this.partitions = partitions;
    }

    public static StringPartitioner instance(int partitions) {
        return new StringPartitioner(partitions);
    }

    @Override
    public int numPartitions() {
        return partitions;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPartition(Object key) {
        int bin = Math.abs(((String)key).hashCode()) % partitions;

        // Sanity check.  This exception is never thrown.
        if (bin >= partitions) {
            throw new RuntimeException("We have a serious problem here!  hashCode is: " + bin + " key is: " + (String)key);
        }
    
        return bin;

    }
}
```

In my test case that fails, `partions == 880`.  During the repartitioning, some workers throw the following exception:

```
23/09/15 08:11:44 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 49.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 46) (192.168.11.14 executor 193): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 16776928 out of bounds for length 880
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.ShuffleExternalSorter.writeSortedFile(ShuffleExternalSorter.java:219)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.ShuffleExternalSorter.closeAndGetSpills(ShuffleExternalSorter.java:444)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.UnsafeShuffleWriter.closeAndWriteOutput(UnsafeShuffleWriter.java:222)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.UnsafeShuffleWriter.write(UnsafeShuffleWriter.java:182)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:54)
at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

It is not possible that my partitioner is returning a value above 879 (`partitions == 880`) given the fact that the `RuntimeException` in my sanity check is never thrown.  How can the partition be `16776928` as the `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` says?  Is Spark modifying the partition numbers being generated by my `StringPartitioner`?

I call the partionioning using the following code:

```java
public void writeIDPartitions(JavaRDD\<String\> textFile, BarneyInit init, long date, String day, int numPartitions)
throws QueryException {

    try{
      // Read in JSON messages, that are one per line in the file.
      // Create key-value pairs consisiting of the message ID (String)
      // and the day of the message (Long).  The starting number of
      // parititions is 100. 
      JavaPairRDD<String, Long> json = textFile.flatMapToPair(new IDPartitionFlatMapFunction(date));
    
      // Reparitition the data
      JavaPairRDD<String, Long> messageDate = json.repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(
        StringPartitioner.instance(numPartitions));
      json = null; // Mark for GC.
    
      // Convert the pair data to dataset rows with columns "message_id" and "date_long"
      LOG.log(Level.INFO, "ID partitions RDD number of partitions is: " + messageDate.getNumPartitions());
      Dataset<Row> parquet = init.getSparkSession().createDataset(messageDate.rdd(),
          Encoders.tuple(Encoders.STRING(),            Encoders.LONG())).toDF(BarneyConstants.Columns.MESSAGE_ID, BarneyConstants.Columns.DATE_LONG);
      LOG.log(Level.INFO, "ID partitions Dataset number of partitions is: " + parquet.rdd().getNumPartitions());
    
      // Write dataset to parquet file        parquet.write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(DirectoryUtils.getIdPartitionDirForDay(init.getBarneyConfig(), day));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      queryException("Exception thrown while generating index", e);
    }

}
```

My cluster configuration is 22 nodes. Each node has 48 cores. Two nodes are for Hadoop namenode and standby.  The primary namenode also runs the Spark master.  The other 20 nodes are for Hadoop and Spark workers and are configured identically as far as I have seen.  Each Spark worker node runs 11 executors with 4 cores each.  I am creating one partition for each core.

I am expecting that the partition ID's generated by my `StringPartitioner` will be honored by the RDD implementation during repartitioning, but that doesn't appear to be happening.  I have run this test with Hadoop 3.3.4 and both Spark 3.3.0 and 3.5.0 and I have encountered the same bug.

I have also tried examining the Spark source code mentioned in the index exception, but the code is too obfuscated for me to determine if the partition IDs being generated by my paritioner are being overridden.